# I have an array of values, how can I plot values using matplotlib so that it looks like a video of 25 seconds

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a array of values

```
2515, 2513, 2513, 2513, 2513, 2512, 2515, 2511, 2526, 2513, 2511, 2500, 2521, 2511, 2523, 2512, 2529, 2513, 2526, 2514, 2518, 2512, 2524, 2512, 2527, 2512, 2521, 2512, 2517, 2514, 2522, 2512, 2521, 2512, 2528, 2511, 2523, 2512, 2518, 2513, 2522, 2512, 2511, 2512, 2524, 2512, 2515, 2512, 2509, 2512, 2515, 2512, 2528, 2512, 2516, 2512, 2527, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2528, 2512, 2529, 2512, 2523, 2511, 2526, 2512, 2521, 2513, 2510, 2512, 2523, 2513, 2500, 2511, 2518, 2512, 2513, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2520, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2519, 2500, 2529, 2511, 2514, 2512, 2522, 2512, 2513, 2512, 2515, 2512]
```

When I am using matplotlib I am getting a graph like this[image: Matplotlib Graph]

The code to get this graph  `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt plt.plot(new3[:100]) plt.show()`

What should I do to plot this graph in say 25 seconds. I mean there should be a live plotting for a similar graph and it should be completed in 25 seconds. I am not looking for multiple graph I want all the updates to be made in a single graph only

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want the x-axis to be in a range of 25 seconds? What does "It should be completed in 25 seconds" mean?

Comment: Yes x axis in range of 25 seconds

Comment: You talk about video. Do you want the plot to be animated?

Comment: Yes I am looking for some sort of animation, just as in the case when we look at a person's heartbeat live something similar to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have. You need matplotlib's animation module and, if you are using Jupyter Notebook and want to see the animation, you need to use `%matplotlib notebook` at the top of your cell.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

data = [2515, 2513, 2513, 2513, 2513, 2512, 2515, 2511, 2526, 2513, 2511, 2500, 2521, 2511, 2523, 
        2512, 2529, 2513, 2526, 2514, 2518, 2512, 2524, 2512, 2527, 2512, 2521, 2512, 2517, 2514, 
        2522, 2512, 2521, 2512, 2528, 2511, 2523, 2512, 2518, 2513, 2522, 2512, 2511, 2512, 2524, 
        2512, 2515, 2512, 2509, 2512, 2515, 2512, 2528, 2512, 2516, 2512, 2527, 2512, 2526, 2512, 
        2528, 2512, 2529, 2512, 2523, 2511, 2526, 2512, 2521, 2513, 2510, 2512, 2523, 2513, 2500, 
        2511, 2518, 2512, 2513, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2520, 2512, 2526, 2512, 2519, 2500, 
        2529, 2511, 2514, 2512, 2522, 2512, 2513, 2512, 2515, 2512]

timePeriod = 25 # 25 seconds
frequency = timePeriod/len(data)
x = np.arange(0, timePeriod, frequency)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
signal, = ax.plot(x, data)


viewWindow = 5 # seconds
windowRange = int(viewWindow/frequency) # takes the size of the window (x limit range) and divides it by the frequency
def animate(i):
    signal.set_ydata(data[i:i+windowRange])  # update the data.
    signal.set_xdata(x[i:i+windowRange])
    plt.xlim(i*frequency, (i+windowRange)*frequency)
    return signal,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=(frequency*1000), frames = 100-windowRange)

ani.save(filename = "movie.gif",writer=animation.PillowWriter(fps=5)) # how to save it as a gif, you can remove this if you want
plt.show()
```

[image]