# Why does my matplotlib animation give an empty axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate a simple demonstration of Benfold's Law. I am expecting an animated bar graph from this code:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,10))

def animate(i):
    plt.title("Iteration: " + str(i))
    plt.plot(np.arange(1,10,1),1000*benford[1:], linestyle="", marker="d",color='r')
    plt.bar(all_leads[i].keys(), all_leads[i].values())
   

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

I get an empty plot.

[Empty Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFjva.png)

The `animate(i)` function works to give a correct individual plot

`animate(10)`

[Image of correctly produced plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9kK1.png)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't have your data, I made a mock animation as best I could from what was provided. First, you have to plot your graph outside of the `animate` function, then you have to update the `x` and `y` data within the `animate` function, lastly -  to loop your animation, you have to set `frames` to some value (we will go with 10 for your case). While this all isn't perfectly in line with your graphs (again, I don't have your data), this should get you started. You can also take a look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198166/i-have-an-array-of-values-how-can-i-plot-values-using-matplotlib-so-that-it-loo/73200013#73200013) for an additional example.

```
%matplotlib notebook # If you are working in jupyter notebook
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,10))
plot, = ax.plot(np.arange(1,10,1),np.arange(1,10,1), linestyle="", marker="d",color='r')

def animate(i):
    plot.set_ydata(np.arange(1,10,1)[i:i+3])
    plot.set_xdata(np.arange(1,10,1)[i:i+3])
    plt.title("Iteration: " + str(i))       

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, frames=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also add an `xlim` argument in the `animate` function to follow your animation across the x-axis:

```
def animate(i):
    plot.set_ydata(np.arange(1,10,1)[i:i+3])
    plot.set_xdata(np.arange(1,10,1)[i:i+3])
    plt.title("Iteration: " + str(i))    
    plt.xlim(i, i+4)
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - much better using axes and now all working. One issue I had was that I was using Jupiter in vscode which doesn't work with %matplotlib notebook - be warned anyone trying this using vscode.

Comment: Excellent. I agree that the animate function is a little... unintuitive? Good to see you got it working